# autoselect shipping method in magento

Tags: php, magento

hey guys I have only one shipping method called JNE http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/suhanto-jne.html in my magento store

I want to the shipping method automaticly selected when my customer fill his city.

I already search and found this : http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9223/#t33602

his solution is like this

```
// find methods loop:
            <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>

//  add checking for free shipping method and setting it as default
                <?php if ($_rate->getCode()=='freeshipping_freeshipping' && !$this->getAddress()->getShippingMethod()) {
                $this->getAddress()->setShippingMethod($_rate->getCode());
            } ?>
```

I don't know where should I place my code in available.html

by the way I have this code in my available.html

---

```
<?php if (!($_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates())): ?>
<strong><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></strong>
```

```
<dl class="shipment-methods">
<?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>

<?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
            <li>
               <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?></li></ul></li></ul>
               <?php else: ?>
                    <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> onclick="shippingMethodStep.save()"/>
                    <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() ?>
                    <strong>
                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>

                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </strong>
                    </label>
               <?php endif ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
    </dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

can you tell me where should I replace or add that solution.

or maybe another solution for autoselect jne shipping method

Comment: If you are using radio-buttons to select shipping method, just edit the shipping method template and to the radio button add attribute "selected" (this should be simplest way).

Comment: yeah but I don't know what to edit. so frustating because don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Very ugly method in your case is to edit

```
<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>
```

within your `input` to

```
<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod() or true){ echo ' checked="checked"';}
```

It's not a very smart reason, but it will work in your case, because every radio button will be selected - in your case it's only one. But it would be better to check if it's only one shipping method. Maybe this also works (I haven't tested it so far):

```
<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod() or count($_shippingRateGroups) == 1){ echo ' checked="checked"';}
```

It counts the number of array elements of the shipping array. If it's only one single element, it sets the `selected`-tag.

Comment: hey stefan thanks for your reply. I try your code and it's checked now but the shipping price doesn't count to billing automaticly.

I have to click it so the billing counted.

I think the shipping price is counted because of this code 

    onclick="shippingMethodStep.save()"

whenever I delete this code after I click the radio it doesn't add shipping price to billing.

any idea to make that called automaticly?

Comment: In magento 1.7 there's a button underneath the radio buttons which call the `shippingMethodStep.save()` method ..? I'm a little bit confused. You can add a javascript area, which will automatically jump to the billing step (so the customer doesn't really see the shipping tab) if the shipping step was loaded. Other option is to place a button underneath the shipping method radio button, so the customer can confirm the shipping method and go to the next step.

Comment: yeah I try to give javascript so the onclick="shippingMethodStep.save()" can be called automaticly.

I ask my friend and he give me this 

<script>shippingMethodStep.save()</script> and I put it after <input> but this god damn code doesn't work haha..

any suggestion for the javascript? thanks